# jquery dialog jumpscroll issue

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I've been searching for solutions for ages but I can't find any good fix for this issue.

Please see the video: screencast.com/t/dKf9mzp1

**The steps:**
Open a dialog box, then in the main dialog box, I have another event to open another dialog box. When I click the bottom contents, it jumps the scroll to top/middle and do nothing which very annoying. But the second time you scroll down and click the content (without closing the 1st & 2nd dialog), it works.

Anybody have solution for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your event handler function, return false and use e.preventDefault() http://api.jquery.com/event.preventdefault/